# Phonegap and jQuery: ajax call to a CGI

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, authorization, cgi

I already found working solutions for ajax call with jQuery and PhoneGap to get for example simple json data. But now i want to send an HTTP Post to a CGI programm. I coded everything and in my browser it worked fine, but when i installed the apk-file on my android 4.1 smartphone, i get an error from the ajax()-call. I now have no idea what to do. The code looks like this and as i said, it works in the browser on my PC (in the browser on android, no matter whether firefox or android browser, it doesnt work, and not as an app).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ip/thing.CGI",
    type: "POST",
    username: "name",
    password: "pw",
    data: params
}).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + data);
});
```

has anyone a solution for this? thank you

SOLUTION:

i just found out that i had to set the request header "Authorization" manually and encode user and password with btoa(). you must add this to the ajax settings array. this for example works then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ip/thing.CGI",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
         "Authorization" : "Basic " +  btoa("user:password")
        },
    data: params
}).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + data);
});
```

so this had nothing to do with invoking a CGI programm or not, but with basic authorization of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin Ressource Sharing might be not allwed.

Enable it with:

either with `crossDomain: true` or `$.support.cors = true`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ip/thing.CGI",
    type: "POST",
    username: "name",
    crossDomain: true,
    password: "pw",
    data: params
}).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + data);
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ip/thing.CGI",
    type: "POST",
    username: "name",
    $.support.cors = true,
    password: "pw",
    data: params
}).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + data);
});
```

Comment: sorry, but as i said cors is not a problem. and the second example just cant work, because you cant write key = value in a json object. $.support.cors = true; has to be somewhere outside. there it helps sometimes, yes. but i found the solution to my problem and changed my original post.

Comment: aah, sorry. But afaik you can simpy use username: "username" and password: "password". There's no need for headers:{....}